# Printing the final row when I need all rows

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I'm trying to skip the first pipe delimited piece of data in my .txt file when reading it with a csv.DictReader. Here is a sample of the data I'm working with:

```
someCSVfile.csv|cust_no,0|streetaddr,1|city,2|state,3|zip,4|phone_home,5|firstname,6|lastname,7|status,9|
someCSVfile1.csv|cust_no,0|streetaddr,1|city,2|state,3|zip,4|phone_home,5|firstname,6|lastname,7|status,9|
```

And here is my code so far:

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open('match_log.txt','rb'), dialect='excel', delimiter='|')

for row in reader:
    skipfirstRow=reader.next()
    skipfirstRowAgain=reader.next()
    Dictreader=csv.DictReader(reader,skipfirstRow)
    print row
```

I've been researching .next() pretty thoroughly, but that doesn't seem to work. When I print my rows, it prints every row, when I don't want the first row (the .csv files) to be printed. Is there another method that may work?

EDIT: Here is my latest code:

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open('match_log.txt','rb'), dialect='excel', delimiter='|')

data = {}

for row in reader:
  filenameVariable = row[0] 
  data = dict(item.split(',') for item in row[1:])

print data
print filenameVariable
```

Right now, data and filenameVariable are printing the final row when I need all rows. I tried .append but that didn't work. What else could I use?

Comment: By row, do you sometimes mean column? So you want to skip `someCSVfile.csv` etc.?

Comment: Yes. I'm sorry. I want to skip that first column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.csv` parts are the first column/field, not the first row.  Advancing `reader` will indeed skip rows, but won't affect what's in each individual row.  (Rows go across!)

If you want to leave off the first item in a sequence, print `row[1:]` instead of `row`.

Comment: Well I feel dumb... rows do go across. Is there a way to skip the first column? Should i split up the pipe delimited lines and skip the first one?

Comment: do what i said and use `row[1:]`  :)  also probably delete all the other attempts, which will do weird things to your reader.

Comment: Wow! that worked! Thanks! I'd hate to bother you again, but is there a way I could make this into a dictionary with 'cust_no','streetaddr',etc... as my keys and 0,1,2,etc... as my values?

Comment: `dict(item.split(',') for item in row[1:])`

Comment: Should i replace the comma with a pipe or leave it as is? And thank you

Comment: you want a comma, because a comma is what separates each key from each value, e.g. `cust_no,0`